# How to upgrade gzip from 1.3.12 to 1.6 on CentOS 6

Tags: centos6, gzip, upgrade

I want to use gzip -k from now on, but it is only available with newer gzip versions. How can I upgrade it on CentOS 6?

Comment: Downvoted why? Is upgrading gzip not part of a server admin's duties?

Answer (score 2):

CentOS geek does not advise upgrade: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=260691#p260691

Comment: Wow, that's a very recent post. Thank you for linking it here. I see that the forum moderator gives the reason that there are too many system dependencies on gzip and cites the errors that would occur with trying to remove gzip. I'm no expert, but I don't completely trust that answer either. Wouldn't a newer version of gzip usually be backwards compatible with slightly older versions? Upgrading is totally different than removing.

Comment: Those arrogant people! Clinging to a 5 year old gzip release! Stupid...

Answer (score 1):

I think two options. The first is to search if this version  (or newer) is available in alternatives repositories. Other option is download and compile the source code.

Sorry for my English level.

Comment: Your English level is quite satisfactory. I prefer using the "yum" command on CentOS whenever possible, and avoiding doing any compiling.

Comment: Thanks!
Another posible option is download the rpm file (http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gzip) for fedora and try to install it... but probably you have a lot of broken dependencies.

Probably the best solution was be proposed by Ian (download a rpms file and rebuild it)

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to download a Fedora srpm and rebuild it on CentOS 6.   Find a local Fedora 22 src mirror at https://admin.fedoraproject.org/mirrormanager/mirrors/Fedora/22/source, navigate to /updates/22/SRPMS/g/ and download gzip-1.6-8.fc22.src.rpm

You can rebuild that on CentOS 6 with:

```
rpmbuild --rebuild gzip-1.6-8.fc22.src.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work around its absence with:

```
gzip -c file > file.gz
gzip -dc file.gz > file
```